# Filtering Nested Array of JSON using javascript (Airtable structure)

Tags: javascript, airtable

I'm not a javascript programmer, but I have a need to write a piece of javascript code (in an HTML page) to filter data from an Airtable JSON array fetched from an API call. I've researched this a lot and tried several options, but none of them worked for me.

I have a simple base on Airtable with the following data:

```
    "records": [
         {
            "id": "reck1GtJ3KfhW9zEO",
            "fields": {
                "highlight": true,
                "price": 15,
                "product_name": "product 1",
                "prod_id": "G001"
            },
            "createdTime": "2021-09-21T20:01:42.000Z"
        },
        {
            "id": "rec7NJh86AK1S9kyN",
            "fields": {
                "highlight": true,
                "price": 50,
                "product_name": "product 2",
                "prod_id": "G002"
            },
            "createdTime": "2021-09-21T20:01:42.000Z"
        },
        {
            "id": "rec5JdK6pbuzsvXA1",
            "fields": {
                "price": 20,
                "product_name": "product 3",
                "prod_id": "G003"
            },
            "createdTime": "2021-09-21T20:01:42.000Z"
        },
        {
            "id": "recV39iR6tBzrmZ5s",
            "fields": {
                "price": 35,
                "product_name": "product 4",
                "prod_id": "G004"
            },
            "createdTime": "2021-09-21T20:01:42.000Z"
        }
    ]
}
```

The code I have is as follows:

```
(async() => {

URL= 'https://api.airtable.com/v0/*removed*';
let response = await fetch(URL, {headers:{ "Authorization":"Bearer *removed*"},});

result = await response.json();

// FILTERATION OPTION 1
//====================
const output_data = result.records.filter(d => d.product_name == "product 1");

console.log(result);
console.log(output_data);

})();
```

Also tried this, didn't work

```
// FILTERATION OPTION 2
//====================
var output_data = result.records.filter(function (el) {
  return
  el.price == 35;
});
```

I want to filter the data above using prod_name or price, or **any fields combination (including id)**. I'd really appreciate your help with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
result.records.filter(d => d.fields.product_name == "product 1");
```

Comment: Cool, np! Just mark this answer as your answer and the thread will be closed :)

Answer (score -1):

Its should be `filter(d => d.fields.product_name == "product 1")`.

because your `product_name` key is  inside your `fields` object of each node in the array.

```js
const result = {"records":[{"id":"reck1GtJ3KfhW9zEO","fields":{"highlight":true,"price":15,"product_name":"product 1","prod_id":"G001"},"createdTime":"2021-09-21T20:01:42.000Z"},{"id":"rec7NJh86AK1S9kyN","fields":{"highlight":true,"price":50,"product_name":"product 2","prod_id":"G002"},"createdTime":"2021-09-21T20:01:42.000Z"},{"id":"rec5JdK6pbuzsvXA1","fields":{"price":20,"product_name":"product 3","prod_id":"G003"},"createdTime":"2021-09-21T20:01:42.000Z"},{"id":"recV39iR6tBzrmZ5s","fields":{"price":35,"product_name":"product 4","prod_id":"G004"},"createdTime":"2021-09-21T20:01:42.000Z"}]};
console.log(result.records.filter(d => d.fields.product_name == "product 1"));
```

Comment: Does this needs an answer? The question can be closed since it is just a typo of an incorrectly accessed object subproperty.

Comment: @Terry Atleast I could say that there was a code error and I fixed that.

Comment: Good that you realized it's essentially the same thing.

Comment: @Fouad If you find this helpful, please approve this answer. Happy to have an upvote aswell.